# if [ awk 'BEGIN{print 0.4*10}' > 1 -eq 0 ]; then echo YES; fi

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, awk

Please help. I'm getting an error when doing this. How ca I fix

```
if [ awk 'BEGIN{print 0.4*10}' > 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo YES; fi
```

Comment: Maybe better tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

shell syntax is tricky to internalize at first. Take a moment to realize that the `if` command doesn't really require any special syntax: it makes its decision based on the **exit status** of the command. Usually you'll see square brackets, but they are really just aliases for the `test` command (more or less).

If you want to work on awk's exit status:

```
if awk 'BEGIN {n = 0.4 * 10; exit (!(n>1))}'; then echo yes; fi
```

If you just want to do some math:

```
result=$(bc <<< "(0.4 * 10) > 1")
if [[ $result = "1" ]]; then echo "YES"; fi

# or, in  one step
if [[ $(bc <<< "(0.4 * 10) > 1") = "1" ]]; then echo "YES"; fi
```

From a bash prompt, type `help if`

Answer (score 2):

Your command has syntax errors. You probably meant to do maths comparison in awk itself and anyway BASH cannot do non-integer maths.

May be you meant this:

```
if [ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ( (0.4*10) > 1) }') -eq 1 ]; then echo YES; fi
YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would work:

```
if [[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print 0.4*10}') > 1 ]]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

But it is not at all clear what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `if`. This will print `yes` if calculation is 4 or `no` if not.

```
[[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print (0.4*10) }') -eq 4 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

or

```
[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print (0.4*10) }') -eq 4 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```